# jQuery UI Autocomplete isn't working with external file in Source

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

So that's it... i have my jQuery Code like this:

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#val').autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input class="searchInput" id="val" name="val" type="text" />
```

PHP (search.php):

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db = mysql_select_db("x",$con);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM opcionais WHERE Opcional LIKE 'Nokia%'");
$result = array();
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $result[] = $linha['Opcional'];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

But here's the deal... when i open my search.php it came to me all the result in json... then, if i try the autocomplete he load all the results....... for example...

In the search.php i receive:

["Nokia","Nokia Lumia"]

Ok... in autocomplete, when i type "LUMIA" the widget load "Nokia" too.
Buuutt..... if i copy the result i get in "search.php" and paste in a variable at the jquery script, the autocomplete works just fine.

Anyone knows why my external source of results doesn't works like if i put the results direct on a variable together with the jQuery Code?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english :-)

**EDIT:**

So i put more images to show what happens... that way it's not working, it's like the SOURCE cannot accept the "$('#val').val()"...

[image: my jquery]
[image: search.php with get statement working]
[image: search.php code]

**SOLVED**

I've solved the problem by my self...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#val').keyup(function(){
        var x = "search.php?ac=" + $('#val').val();
        $('#val').autocomplete({
            source: x,
            minLenght:5,
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

thanks for all responses :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is natural for autocomplete(AC) to work when you use the javascript variable.. because AC will itself find out matching results from that variable (array). On the other hand, if you call `search.php`, AC will treat whatever it returns as the matching result, and will not try to match any further.

I actually think your query in the PHP script is somehow wrong and you need to debug that. You are typing `LUMIA` and the script is returning ['Nokia'] etc. That means it is running this query

`SELECT * FROM opcionais WHERE Opcional LIKE 'Nokia%'`

Whereas it should run

`SELECT * FROM opcionais WHERE Opcional LIKE 'LUMIA%'`

So there you go.

**EDIT :**

It seems that you are not sending the keyword `LUMIA` via ajax at all. [Check documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source). What you need to do is change the js this way:

```
$('#val').autocomplete({
    source: "search.php?keyword="+$('#val').val(),
});
```

And in php:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM opcionais WHERE Opcional LIKE 'Nokia ".$_GET['keyword']."%'");
```

Or maybe for better result:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM opcionais WHERE Opcional LIKE '%".$_GET['keyword']."%'");
```

In addition I'd suggest using prepared statements in your query, these `mysql` functions are [outdated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Actually, the Query is returning every NOKIA CELLPHONE MODEL in the database... and i have 10 models with LUMIA in the name... so when i made the query with "NOKIA%" and i type "LUMIA" should return all "NOKIA LUMIA XX" that exists... got?

Comment: It seems that you are not sending the keyword `LUMIA` via ajax. Check my edit.

Comment: I've updated some screens with your tip... but still doesn't working :(

Observe in the jQuery code, if i put `<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $('#val').autocomplete({
  source: "search.php?ac=lumia",
  minLength: 5,
 });
});
</script>` specifying the GET statement, the plugin works well... :(

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, I think you should add the script below your HTML. Also looking at your solution. you should not be calling `autocomplete()` in a `keyup()` event. That is quite wrong.

Comment: Ok, i tried to use your tip putting the script below my html but without success too... and using the `autocomplete()` in a `keyup()` worked well for me... so i think it's a solution. But thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Returned format should be like that:

```
[
      {
            "label": "Nokia",
            "value": "1"
      },
      {
            "label": "Lumia",
            "value": "2"
      }
]
```

of course there is some variations and may be new versions of autocomplete have a bit different style. but always should be a pair of label and value.

You can add option `dataType: 'json'` to the request too.

I think that returning that kind of JSON will work too:

```
{1:'Nokia',2:'Lumia'}
```

Comment: i have exactly that return in Search.php:

`{1:'Nokia',2:'Lumia'}`

And that time i can't even get AC work

i've downloaded the last version of AutoComplete from jqueryUI